# VSCode debug subprocess.call

Tags: python, debugging, subprocess

Current launch.json looks like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "subProcess": true,
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
    ]
}
```

The code:

```
cmd = (
    "a-pip-package"
    " --verbose"
    " --do-something"
)
print(cmd)
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

I can add a print statement into the pip package and see that it in fact prints. However, when I add a breakpoint, the debugger never hits.

e.g.

`/home/me/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip-package/a-pip-package.py`

```
def main():
  print("hey!")
  ...
```

I got the above path from doing something like:

`subprocess.call(["which", "a-pip-package"])`

Results in:  `/home/me/venv/bin/a-pip-package`

That file looks like:

```
#!/home/me/venv/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from pip_package.a_pip_package import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

In summation, I believe that the file that is actually executed is `/home/me/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip-package/a-pip-package.py`, but when I add a breakpoint in that file, VSCode never breaks there.